# Python pandas: Faster way than numpy.select?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, select

I have a dataframe with two columns looking like this:

```
      GebTyp BAK
0         RH   C
1        MFH   A
2         RH   J
3         RH   F
4         RH   K
...      ...  ..
25046    MFH   C
25047    MFH   G
25048    MFH   I
25049    MFH   A
25050    MFH   B
```

And another one with values for each pair of these two columns.

```
   BAK  EFH/DHH     RH    MFH    GMH     HH
0    A    231.0  222.0  265.0  186.0  156.0
1    B    271.0  222.0  204.0  186.0  156.0
2    C    214.0  186.0  222.0  197.0  167.0
3    D    242.0  183.0  236.0  201.0  171.0
4    E    184.0  155.0  188.0  196.0  143.0
5    F    198.0  179.0  162.0  158.0  121.0
6    G    134.0  145.0  138.0  134.0  104.0
7    H    159.0  118.0  143.0  103.0   73.0
8    I    120.0  110.0  119.0   97.0   87.0
9    J     91.0   89.0   86.0   75.0   69.0
10   K      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
11   L      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

I can assign each individual value correctly with `numpy.select` like this:

```
def GWB()
    conditions = [
        (mc["BAK"] == "A" & mc["GebTyp"] == "EFH/DHH"),
        (mc["BAK"] == "A" & mc["GebTyp"] == "RH"),
        (mc["BAK"] == "A" & mc["GebTyp"] == "MFH"),
        (mc["BAK"] == "A" & mc["GebTyp"] == "GMH"),
        (mc["BAK"] == "A" & mc["GebTyp"] == "HH"),
    ]

    values = [
        (231),
        (222),
        (265).
        (186),
        (156)
    ]
    df["result"] = np.select(conditions,values)
GWB()
```

But this would result in roughly 80 lines of code, also in this case I'm working only with the first dataframe, assigning the values manually. I was wondering if there would be a faster/shorter way to do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2.melt('BAK', value_name='result', var_name='GebTyp'), 
          how='left', 
          on=['BAK','GebTyp'])
print (df)
   GebTyp BAK  result
0      RH   C   186.0
1     MFH   A   265.0
2      RH   J    89.0
3      RH   F   179.0
4      RH   K     NaN
5     ...  ..     NaN
6     MFH   C   222.0
7     MFH   G   138.0
8     MFH   I   119.0
9     MFH   A   265.0
10    MFH   B   204.0
```

Comment: Will this also work if I have several other columns in df1? Didn't mention them to not stress out the extent of the question

Comment: @Jonas - I think yes, but also is posible add `on` parameter for set columns for join.